# GetThreadID in assembly

Tags: delphi, x86, inline-assembly, fastmm

I read the source code of FastMM4, and notice this interesting function

```
function GetThreadID: Cardinal;
{$ifdef 32Bit}
asm
  mov eax, FS:[$24]
end;
{$else}
begin
  Result := GetCurrentThreadID;
end;
{$endif}
```

I've tested it, and it works, so my question is any explanation why it works?

Comment: And another [must see link](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/TEB.html) on TEB. [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms686708) is useless for this subject.

Comment: On the contrary the MS documentation is excellent. Since this is private implementation the correct documentation strategy for private implementation details is to keep it private.

Comment: @DoctorLai, I'm curious, why do you call reading memory with **magic** displacement an "effecient"?

Comment: @David Heffernan, makes sense, but only until these private details published. Since when, it becomes just poorly documented details.

Comment: @user539484  you are right, actually i didn't know how the Win32 API GetCurrentThreadID is implemented. maybe they both use the same thing.

Comment: @Doctor You can step into the winapi call. And of course it uses TEB.

Comment: @user and then ms are probably stuck with the current offsets until the end of time!

Comment: @DoctorLai, yes, Windows implementation reads TEB, **but** they use helper function [`NtCurrentTeb/ZwCurrentTeb`](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/NtCurrentTeb.html) to attain certain grade of flexibility of private implementation.

Comment: @David Heffernan, does "excellent" MS documentation shed at least some light onto discussed subject?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The x86 register FS points to the [Thread Information Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) in Windows. The value in TIB at address FS+0x24 contains ID of the current thread. By moving the value to eax, which is used to pass the function return value, GetThreadID returns the current thread ID.

Comment: so, it means i can do the same with FS+0x20 that returns the Process ID. this must be more efficient than the one defined in Windows unit.

Comment: It may be marginally more efficient but I am here to tell you that fetching PID and TID is not the bottleneck in your program.

Comment: @David, Reading other posts from OP, I don't think OP has a bottleneck at all. He's more into extreme optimization kind of thing... perhaps :)

Comment: @kobik What's funny here, is that the implementation of `GetCurrentThreadId` simply read the TEB.  I mean, what else would it do? I would not accept the code in the question into my codebase.

Comment: @David, "I would not accept the code in the question into my codebase" - I'm with you on this.

Comment: @doctorlai: if you look at how winapi implementa this, it does the same thing really... [related stuff](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2010/06/18/fun-with-asm/)

Comment: @kobib  can I ask what is 'OP'?

Comment: @David Heffernan  yes I agree with you. getting IDs never is the bottleneck.

Comment: @Remko  so the advantage of doing such is to save the function calling  overhead ?

Comment: @DoctorLai Why do you want to save function calling overhead? Why don't you want simple code that is easy to maintain?

Comment: @DoctorLai at the expense of breaking stuff, like in x64 or windows rt. The performance benefit is probably not even measureable so I would stick to winapi! (for play the asm is cool ;-) )

Comment: @Remko, it is unlikely a "fun", look more like dirty hacks.

Comment: @user539484 what is dirty about it, it is 100% confirming to msdn docs and intel specs however limited to current implementation

Comment: @Remko, most assemblers supports structs (including BASM), you are using magic displacements instead, creating the grounds for the questions like this one. This is not cool.

Comment: @Samuli Hynönen, a minor, but important correction: FS is x386 register, not just x86.

Comment: Do you use FastMM4, @David? If so, then "accept the code in the question into my codebase" is exactly what you've done. The assembler implementation of `GetThreadID` has existed since revision 1. The conditional call to `GetCurrentThreadID` was added in revision 36 for 64-bit support of Delphi XE2.

Comment: @Rob Not really. I mean the codebase which I manage. If the code had used GetCurrentThreadId from the start, the change in r36 would not have been needed.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses the information stored in the [Thread Environment Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block)